# Get collection values without loop in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have `hotels` and `services` tables with many to many relationship. I want to get services of specific hotel without using foreach or forelse loop from one line of code.

This is how I tried to do that:

```
$hotel->services->pluck('name')
```

Result I get:

```
["Free Wi-Fi","Free Parking"]
```

Result is an array of values, I want it to be without brackets and quotes. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you tack on `->implode(', ')` you'll get `"Free Wi-FI, Free Parking"`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-implode, is that what you mean?

Comment: Tried this and works just fine:
`$hotel->services->implode('name', ', ')`

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for a hint!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to add your solution below as a self-answer to properly close this question. Cheers 

Comment: @lasshak if `$hotel->services` are not loaded, you should do `$hotel->services()->pluck('name')->toArray()->implode(', ')` instead.

Comment: @N69S `->toArray()->implode()` is an error; `->implode()` is a Collection method: `Call to a member function implode() on array`. Also, if `services` isn't loaded, calling `->services` will load it, so that is redundant.

Comment: @TimLewis if service is not loaded, no need to go through mutators and caster and object initiation when you can use pluck from the QueryBuilder. Notice using `->services()` instead of `->services` You're right tho, i meant this `implode(', ', $hotel->services()->pluck('name')->toArray())` or `$hotel->services()->pluck('name')->implode(', ')`

Comment: @N69S Right, but I mean `services` will perform `services()->get()` if it hasn't been loaded. If it has been loaded, and you do `services()`, you're overriding that eager loading and forcing a new query, so I'd argue against doing `services()` over `services`. But regardless, either approach is acceptable, depends on specific use case. And yeah, all good on the `implode(...)` vs `->implode(...)` 

Comment: @TimLewis the difference is that using `->services()` (if it has not been loaded or eager loaded) will run `pluck()` **instead** of `get()` wich will also prevent the instantiation of the models `Service::class` + extra.

Comment: @N69S Yeah, fair enough. For a single `Hotel` instance, `->services->pluck()` or `->services()->pluck()` would be fine. For multiple `Hotel` instances, i.e. in a loop, this would be an N+1 query issue, so again, depends on the use case 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
$hotel->services->implode('name', ', ')
```